# jQuery UI droppable, triggering drop event from code

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I am creating scheduler plugin. I have already created scheduling mechanism: event is dragged on scheduler, javascript function gathers data about this event and at the end data is loaded to the database. After refreshing the site I need to see already created events. I want to achieve this by triggering drop event on droppable. Is it possible to trigger drop event on (jquery) droppable element directly from code? If yes, how to accomplish this?

Comment: If you retrigger the event, won't it repeat the scheduling ?

Comment: Hmm it will :/ So I should create a new function to handle this loading process. I'm doing this project in rails, is there a way to pass data from rails model to javascript function?

Comment: On landing or refresh, you are looking to prerender your currently recorded schedule, in a format that agrees with your subsequent client side jq-ui logic. I don't know rails, but I wouldn't think you need to speak to the js for this step.

Comment: There is one more way I think drop event can be used without repetition. I believe that creating global boolean variable, that will decide whether to update db or not, would solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, obviously your code controls what happens when whatever event is fired. If it makes it any clearer, I am proposing you open a book and read what is printed on the page (prerendering from db), while you are proposing to quickly rewrite the page (recreating the situation clientside). You know best what makes sense in your situation.

Comment: @Mark it would not make sense to trigger drop event when page loads. I am assuming you are using some server side scripting. I would advise that the server side script gathers the current schedule of details. This can be done inline when loading the page or via API.